# Setting cursor position in SWT after clearing the text

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to clear the text written in Text box and place the cursor at the start of the text box after ENTER KEY is pressed. I am able to get the text, clear the text, but the cursor always ends up in the second line of the text box.

```
final Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
gridLayout.numColumns = 1;
shell.setLayout(gridLayout);

final Text text1 = new Text (shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);
text1.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

text1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.keyCode == SWT.CR) {
            String textData = text1.getText();
            text1.setText("");
            text1.setSelection(0);
        }
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Should the text box be a single line only? If so, don't use `SWT.MULTI`.

Comment: It should be multi-line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that after getting the text and clearing the box the key listener is trying to do its job and answer the `ENTER`-key press.

What you want to do in this case is to tell him: "I got the information I needed, you don't have to proceed". You do this by setting the `doit` flag of the `KeyEvent` to `false`:

```
text1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.keyCode == SWT.CR) {
            String textData = text1.getText();
            text1.setText("");

            // HERE IS THE IMPORTANT CODE PART, NO SELECTION IS NEEDED
            e.doit = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, change the cursor position rather after key released :

```
text1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.keyCode == SWT.CR) {
            String textData = text1.getText();
            text1.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.keyCode == SWT.CR) {
            text1.setSelection(0);
        }
    }
});
```